# Passing multiple arguments to sudo within function

Tags: bash, shell, function

```
foo (){
            sudo -- sh -c "cd /home/rob; echo \"$@\""
}
```

I'm trying to make a bash function in `.bashrc` that will sudo, change to a particular directory and then run a Python command. For demo purposes I have changed this to echo in the above example.

Even though I have quoted `$@` to pass all arguments to my echo command, it only works with one:

```
$ foo 1
1
$ foo 1 2
2": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
2": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

What gives? How can I pass multiple arguments to this function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `set -v` to your function and you will see what is happening:

```
$ f (){ set -v; sudo -- sh -c "cd /tmp; echo \"$@\""; } 
$ f 1 2
+ sudo -- sh -c 'cd /tmp; echo "1' '2"'
```

What is happening?  Your use of `$@` has created two strings that have been single quoted to `cd /tmp; echo "1` and `2"`.  You can use `$*` if you dont want this splitting. See the bash man page section on *Special Parameters*:

> @ ... When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter
>    expands to a separate word. ... If ... within a word, the expansion of the
>    first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word,
>    and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last part of
>    the original word.

So in your case the single string (or word) "xxx$@yyy" expands to 2 strings 'xxx1' and '2yyy'. You can test this using `set -- 1 2 3` to set `$@` and then use `printf ">%s<" "$@"` to see the number of words that `"$@"` becomes (as the printf will repeat the format for each argument):

```
$ set -- 1 2 3
$ printf ">%s< " "x$@y"
>x1< >2< >3y<
$ printf ">%s< " "x$*y"
>x1 2 3y<
```

If you want to pass arguments to `sh -c command` one hack is to place them after the single command as arguments, but this may not work on all shells:

```
f (){ set -v; sudo -- sh -c 'cd /tmp; echo "$@"' sh "$@"; }
f 1 2
+ sudo -- sh -c 'cd /tmp; echo "$@"' sh 1 2
```

The extra `sh` argument is because the first arg is taken by the shell as the name of the process.

Comment: Thanks although `set -v` just seems to give me `__vte_prompt_command` in the output.

Comment: That seems to be some sort of function for the vte terminal emulator squatting the interactive shell prompt. You might want to try a separate `bash --norc` or similar for testing in a more neutral setting.

Comment: I will mark this as answer - thanks. Why does `$@` cause single quoting of the two strings? Why is there then a mixture of single quotes and double quotes? Your solution works, but I'm still at a loss why you need `sh` when you don't need it for other functions where I've used double quotes around `$@`.

Comment: I added the relevent section from the bash man page to my answer. Note, the single quotes is just an artifact of `set -v` so that it can show you where each string (or word) ends. Your `\"` is at this stage just an ordinary character. It is only when `sh -c` parses the command that it will see the character as a double quote.